# Trying to split a string based on the character "|" doesn't work

Tags: r

I have a text string that I want to split based on the character `|` (the vertical bar/pipe, that is, the character with ascii code 124).

When trying to do this, my string is split on every character. That is, the following code

```
string <- "Hello | Good bye!"
split <- strsplit(string, "|")
print(split[[1]])
```

generates this output

```
[1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "|" " " "G" "o" "o" "d" " " "b" "y" "e" "!"
```

If I just change the `|` sign to `/` instead (or any other character), it works as expected. That is, the following code

```
string <- "Hello / Good bye!"
split <- strsplit(string, "/")
print(split[[1]])
```

generates this output

```
[1] "Hello "     " Good bye!"
```

which is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `fixed = TRUE` to interpret meta-characters such as `|` literally:

```
string <- "Hello | Good bye!"
strsplit(string, "|", fixed = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "Hello "     " Good bye!"
```

Similarly,

```
strsplit("Hello . Good bye!", ".")[[1]]
#[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
strsplit("Hello . Good bye!", ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "Hello "     " Good bye!"
```

---

Alternatively, you can manually escape such characters with double backslashes,

```
strsplit("Hello | Good bye!", "\\|")[[1]]
#[1] "Hello "     " Good bye!"
```

or wrap them with `\\Q...\\E`, which will escape all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
strsplit("Hello | Good bye!", "\\Q|\\E")[[1]]
#[1] "Hello "     " Good bye!"
```

Comment: Alternatively, escape it: `strsplit(string, "\\|")`